# How to properly set response headers when streaming download of an image from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, image, google-cloud-platform, download, google-cloud-storage

I have this so far:

```
app.get('/:image/:size.:ext', (req, res) => {
  const remote = bucket.file(`${req.params.image}/${req.params.size}.${req.params.ext}`)
  if (req.query.download == 'true') {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpg')
    res.set('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename="${req.params.image}.${req.params.size}.${req.params.ext}";` )
    res.set('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
    // header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename))
  }
  // if (isProd)
  //   res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=604800')
  remote.createReadStream({ validation: false })
    .on('error', error => {
      console.log(error)
      res.send(`data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7`)
    })
    .pipe(res)
})
```

In that `download=true` block, I am not sure how to get the filesize, if it is somehow passed in through `remote` stream, or if I should be storing that in a database somewhere, or otherwise get is somehow.

Comment: I think you are asking how to retrieve the size of a GCS Object?  If so, then we can look at the size property of the returned metadata.  Here is a link to the corresponding API ... https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.5.x/File#getMetadata

Answer (score 0):

You can get metadata.size from 
[getMetadata(options, callback)](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.3.x/File#getMetadata) that returns Promise containing GetFileMetadataResponse

```
storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .file(filename)
  .getMetadata()
  .then(results => {
    const metadata = results[0];

    console.log(`File: ${metadata.name}`);
    console.log(`Size: ${metadata.size}`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```